# How can I make a container that contains different sized images fit together while maintaining the container shape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been working on a site for a makeup artist and i wanted to make the picture layout like this: http://www.jasoncgriffin.com/photos/

How would I go about doing that? I've googled and researched a lot to try and get that result but I've settled for kind of hacking the background image on top of the image itself.

Comment: I think what you want is a Masonry layout. You should find decent tutorials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

 $(window).load(function(){

  $('.masonry').masonry({
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
   gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
   itemSelector: '.item'
  });

 });
    
}(jQuery));
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: xxspx) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2.25% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 31.8333333333%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 31.8333333333%;
    margin-bottom: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 23.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.875% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 18.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.8% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 15.1666666667%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 15.1666666667%;
    margin-bottom: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="masonry">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [here](https://codepen.io/jdlaplan/pen/Aowpj)